# Recorrer un arreglo de objetos en un json y unirlo con otro arreglo de objetos de otro json con javascript

Tags: json, reactjs, objeto

Tengo un json asi

```
aca =[  {
    "post_id": 9335,
    "post_title": "Comunicación efectiva para mejorar resultados",
    "post_status": "draft",
  },
  {
    "post_id": 9336,
    "post_title": "Creadores de videos",
    "post_status": "draft",
  },  etc ...]

y otro con esta info
ids = [
  {
    "post_id": 9345,
    "Ids": "9"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 9162,
    "Ids": 76
  },
  {
    "post_id": 9163,
    "Ids": "10"
  }, etc...]
```

Necesito pasar al array "aca" el Ids del array "ids" cuando coincidan los post_id de cada objeto.
O sea que cuando cac.post_id = ids.post_id el objeto de cac incluya la propiedad Ids: 'Numero'
Probe muchas cosas, este fue mi ultimo intento

```
const all = async () => {
    const ids = await idsJson();
    const cac = await codoacodo();
    const all = []
    for (i=0; i< cac.length; i++) {

    for (j=0; j< ids.length; i++) {
    for(el in cac[i]) {
        for(el in ids[j]) {
        if (cac[i][post_id] === ids[j][post_id]) {
            all.push(...cac[i], ids[j])
        } else {
            all.push(...cac[i])
        }
    }   }    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(all))
    }
    return all
}
    all()
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const aca = [
  {
    "post_id": 9345,
    "post_title": "Comunicación efectiva para mejorar resultados",
    "post_status": "draft",
  },
  {
    "post_id": 9336,
    "post_title": "Creadores de videos",
    "post_status": "draft",
  },
];

const ids = [
  {
    "post_id": 9345,
    "Ids": "9"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 9162,
    "Ids": 76
  },
  {
    "post_id": 9163,
    "Ids": 10
  }
];

aca.forEach(elem => {
  const [ match ] = ids.filter(id => id.post_id === elem.post_id);
  if(match) {
    elem['Ids'] = match.Ids;
  }
});

console.log(aca);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Si el Array llamado `ids` no contiene elementos con campo `post_id` repetidos, el código anterior funcionará perfectamente.**

Estoy usando el método [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para recorrer el Array llamado `aca`. La ventaja de este método es que recorre todo el Array y que puedo alterar el contenido orginal del mismo.

Dentro de la función que se ejecuta por cada elemento de `aca`, hago uso del método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para obtener el valor que coincida con el campo `post_id` de `ids`. Si no existen coincidencias, el Array devuelto por el método `filter` será un Array vacío, por lo tanto `match` será `undefined` y no entrará en la condición.

Pero si acaso hay una coincidencia, puede asignar al elemento de `aca` el valor de `post_id`. Como el elemento de `aca` no posee un atributo llamado `post_id`, debo usar la notación de corchetes `[ ]` para crear dicho atributo y asignarle un valor.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que en tu comentario planteas que `cac` no es un Array y debes usar `Array.from()`, entonces lo mejor es convertirlo en Array directamente al momento de obtenerlo:

```js
const cac = Array.from(await codoacodo());
```

De esta manera ya podrás aplicar directamente el método `forEach` sobre tu variable.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, Intente con tu codigo y me decia que cac no es una funcion con lo cual añadi lo siguiente Array.from(cac).forEach(elem => {
        const [ match ] = ids.filter(id => id.post_id === elem.post_id);
        if(match) {
          elem['Ids'] = match.Ids;
        }
      });
      
      console.log(cac); Pero no me agrega la propidad Ids al objeto del array cac

Comment: Porque `Array.from()` crea un nuevo Array a partir del iterable. En cuanto pueda edito la respuesta con la solución.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio por tu respuestas, con estos cambios me genera un array vacio. No se por que aca no lo toma como array, es un json que responde una api.   Asi lo puse y me consologuea [] .          const all = async () => {
    const ids = await idsJson();
    const cac = Array.from(await codoacodo());
    cac.forEach(elem => {
        const [ match ] = ids.filter(id => id.post_id === elem.post_id);
        if(match) {
          elem['Ids'] = match.Ids;
        }
      });
      console.log(cac)   
}

Comment: Ya quedo, estaba entrando mal a la info del json. Es aca.data  y Ids.data   mil gracias!!!

Comment: Has debug de lo que ocurre dentro de `forEach`. Asegúrate que existan coincidencias. Que te devuelva un Array vacío significa que no hace `match`. Saludos

Comment: Que bueno. Si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como válida. Saludos

Comment: La marque pero como soy nueva y no tengo reputacion aun no se visualiza. Gracias!